# Adding gtag script to an external JavaScript file

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I have added the following code to my webpage to send event info to Google Analytics:

```
<head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-144340016-1"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-144340016-1');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->
</head>
<body>
    <a id='lin1' href="cool.com" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'cat1', 'event_label': 'lab1'});">
    </a>
</body
```

Now I don't want to use the inline `onclick` event on the html and I want to move this bit to a separate JavaScript code, so something like this:

**my.js**

```
$('#lin1').click(function() {
    gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'cat1', 'event_label': 'lab1'});
});
```

An then add **my.js** at the bottom of my webpage. Is there any issue with this approach? All the documentations that I have seen add the `gtag` event directly to the HTML, that's why I wanted to make sure if there is no downside with what I am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with having a function library with function that send hits to Analytics. Eventually the documentation suggests inserting the snippet (`gtag.js`) directly into the HTML, in the `head` (but this looks like you already do).